# Git log - To get the history graph of tags

Tags: git

I would like to get the history graph of tags (only) of a repo with a very complex history.

In particular, it should:

- display commits that have been tagged
- display the result as a graph

Example:

```
* Commit 9
* Commit 8
|\
* | Commit 7
| * Commit 6
| |\
| * | Commit 5
|/| |
* | | Commit 4
| | * Commit 3
| |/
| * Commit 2
|/
* Commit 1
```

If commit 1, 3 and 9 are tagged, the solution would be:

```
* Commit 9
* Commit 3
* Commit 1
```

If commit 1, 3, 5 and 9 are tagged, the solution would be:

```
* Commit 8
|\
* | Commit 5
| * Commit 3
|/
* Commit 1
```

If commit 1, 3, 4, 5 and 9 are tagged, the solution would be:

```
* Commit 9
|\
| |\
| * | Commit 5
|/| |
* | | Commit 4
| | * Commit 3
| |/
|/
* Commit 1
```

I cannot find any answer. I started my investigations with `git log --all --oneline --graph`
But then I got lost in the git log documentation and google didn't help me neither.
I need your expertise.

Best regards,
Adrien

Comment: To get the "solution" you have drawn, you would need to write your own tool. The reason is that you are asking that Git should show you a lie, and Git is not going to do that.

Comment: @matt: yes, but `--simplify-by-decoration` will get something that might be good enough for the OP's purposes.

Answer (score 2):

I think you want

```
git log --tags --oneline --graph --simplify-by-decoration
```

Comment: Nice solution, and even with --first-parent: git log --tags --oneline --graph --simplify-by-decoration --first-parent  But I lose merge information